# React Native PagerView Webpack TypeError on web

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, webpack

I'm using the PagerView component from 'react-native-pager-view' at https://github.com/callstack/react-native-pager-view.

Short backstory my app is intended to be available on all 3 platforms (Android, iOS, web). I know that this  library doesn't support web, I'm trying to compromise by not using this component on web by trying to conditionally use this component if not on web.

I tried to create an if conditional block that is always false to test it out and it seems that it still tries to read the component on compilation.

```js
import PagerView from 'react-native-pager-view';

const render = () => {
  let view = <View></View>;
  if (false) { // Ideally (Platform.OS !== "web")
    // Code works if I comment out the code line below
    view = <PagerView ...></PagerView>;
  }
  return <View>{view}</View>;
}
```

Here is the following error message on web if I try to run the code like above.

> TypeError:
> Object(react_native_web_dist_index__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__["requireNativeComponent"])
> is not a function. (In
> 'Object(react_native_web_dist_index__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__["requireNativeComponent"])(VIEW_MANAGER_NAME)',
> 'Object(react_native_web_dist_index__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__["requireNativeComponent"])'
> is an instance of Object)

I think this could be solved with some kind of Webpack configuration but unfortunately I'm not too savvy on that.

These are also some additional error messages I got on the Expo Metro Bundler page

> node_modules/react-native-pager-view/lib/module/PagerView.js Attempted
> import error: 'react-native-web/dist/index' does not contain a default
> export (imported as 'ReactNative').

> node_modules/react-native-pager-view/lib/module/PagerViewNative.js
> Attempted import error: 'requireNativeComponent' is not exported from
> 'react-native-web/dist/index'.

Any help or suggestions would be much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Did you find a solution ?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I dealt with it ([from doc](https://reactnative.dev/docs/platform-specific-code)).

You can also use the .native.js extension when a module needs to be shared between NodeJS/Web and React Native but it has no Android/iOS differences. This is especially useful for projects that have common code shared among React Native and ReactJS.

For example, say you have the following files in your project:

```
Container.js # picked up by Webpack, Rollup or any other Web bundler
Container.native.js # picked up by the React Native bundler for both Android and iOS (Metro)
```

You can still import it without the .native extension, as follows:

```
import Container from './Container';
```